# Difference in xm and xl list

Tags: xen

I'm new to xen toolstacks - trying `xe`, `xl`.

Now i've created a guest os:

```
sudo virt-install -r 512 -n centos -f /dev/sdb --nographics --location http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64
```

And want to see it in a list of DomU guests. Using `xm`:

```
[egor@xen ~]$ sudo xm list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  1024     1     r-----    160.8
centos                                           512     1                 0.0
```

But using `xl`:

```
[egor@xen ~]$ sudo xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs  State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  1024     1     r-----     164.8
```

Could you help me - why there is no `centos` in `xl` list?

Comment: It looks like `xl` by default is not listing domUs that aren't currently running...

Comment: But if so how do I get guests names to start them?

Comment: Don't use `xl`? Use `xm` or `libvirt` / `virsh`; or look at the guest config files in `/etc/xen`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libvirt doesn't support latest xen tool stack.

xm is old tool stack. xl is new tool stack.

maybe virt-instool used old tool stack. so xl can not recognize domU.